# How to read a json decoded array with php?

Tags: php, json

I have the following array and I can't figure out how to get any values out of it, this is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aure] => test
            [menu] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pizza] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Tomato & Cheese] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [small] => 5.50
                                    [large] => 9.75
                                )

                            [onion] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [small] => 5.50
                                    [large] => 9.75
                                )

                        )

                    [Special Dinners] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Chicken Wings Dinner] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [price] => 15.80
                                )

                            [onion] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [small] => 5.50
                                    [large] => 9.75
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

would you be able to give me an example of how can I get the price for a small Tomato & cheese pizza?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array[0]->menu->pizza->{"Tomato & Cheese"}->small;
```

I have used curly brackets because I'm not able to get "Tomato & Cheese" without them (they have spaces)

This will give you all pizzas

```
$pizzas = (array) $array[0]->menu->pizza;
foreach($pizzas as $pizzaname => $choices){
    echo $pizzaname." (small) is for ".$choices->small."<br />";
    echo $pizzaname." (large) is for ".$choices->large."<br />";
}
```

Comment: dam that looks easy :),  thanks, is there a way to do it without knowing the names of pizzas

Comment: thanks @genesis, though the last bit of code, the foreach loop, is not showing anything.

Comment: this is the result of you $pizzas array : Array ( [Tomato & Cheese] => stdClass Object ( [small] => 5.50 [large] => 9.75 ) [onion] => stdClass Object ( [small] => 5.50 [large] => 9.75 ) )

Comment: @aurel: Edited. Execuse me for late response

Answer (score 1):

If your names are not only alphanumeric, consider setting the `assoc` parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to true to get a nested dictionary instead of objects.

However, you can still access strange member names, using the following syntax:

```
echo 'Large t&c: ' . jsonArray[0]->menu->pizza->{'Tomato & Cheese'}->large;
```

Comment: i will need to look into that "assoc" this as I dont know what that is. Is there a way to get the same results without knowing the name of "menu" and "pizza"?

Comment: @aurel Yup. Setting `assoc` to true allows you use all [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), and you can simply iterate over them, for example in a nested for loop.